# Highcharts preventing area graphs from overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following code using Highcharts:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mj0m3oo/

As you can see, both graphs are overlapping and have a `fillOpacity` of `0.2`, which makes the overlapping area have a different color. Is it possible to prevent them from overlapping?

I need the opacity effect (to be able to see the background) and still maintain the same color, without the first mixing with the one on the layer behind.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you could try an arearange (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange). Area charts start their fill from zero to series value at each point.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are trying to acheive.  Can you add an image of your desired outcome?

Comment: sounds like maybe you're looking for stacking - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.stacking but yes, it's unclear what you're asking.